# Log rotate using perl Logfile::Rotate

Tags: perl, logrotate, size

The below script works when executed on CentOS, but it doesn't rotate logs based on size. A new log is generated every time I execute this script. Can anyone tell me how to make this script work based on size?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Logfile::Rotate;
my $logfile = new Logfile::Rotate(
  File => '/var/log/remotehost/fakepath/Syslog.log',
  Count => 100,
  Gzip => '/usr/bin/gzip',
  size => 1*1024*1024,
  sub {
    open my $PID, '<', '/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service' or
    die "Unable to open pid file:$!\n";
    chomp(my $pid = <$PID>);
    close $PID;
    kill 'HUP', $pid;
  }
);
# Log file locked (really) and loaded. Now let's rotate it.
$logfile->rotate();
# make sure the log file is unlocked (destroying object unlocks file)
undef $logfile;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `Logfile::Rotate` does not rotate based on size, which should be unsurprising since nowhere does its documentation say it does. Perhaps the simplest way to rotate based on size would be to wrap the call to `rotate` within an if, for example:

```
if (-s '/var/log/remotehost/fakepath/Syslog.log' > 1048576) {
    $log->rotate();
}
```

This should rotate the logs only when the named file is larger than 1MB (the size is given in bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply dhag.. Can you check the edited script .. earlier I posted wrong script

Comment: The code from your original question looked correct, apart from the fact that it would rotate unconditionally. Wrapping the call to `rotate` within a test, as I did in my answer, should do the trick. `Logfile::Rotate` does not seem to support a `size` key as in your edited question.